# 3D human Hand design and control via Arduino

Tags: animation, 3d, arduino, blender

I want to design a 3D human hand and control it via signal generated from my Arduino kit. I designed a 3D hand in Blender but how to give the signal generated from Arduino to add life into it. Which tool I should use.

For example I have designed an arbitrary frequency generator. And I want at a particular frequency the Hand will mimic Pinching, or to Fist. Which tool I can use to use the generated signal as input to a Programming interface and output of the Program as a Animated 3D hand.

Please help guys......

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may want to look at the work done for the [leap motion device](http://slsi.dfki.de/software-and-resources/hand-tracking-for-3d-editing/).

Answer (score 0):

Python would seem the obvious solution to this, as it can interface directly with Blender.

I'm not sure how your controller works with frequencies, but chances are there's a library or a way to handle it in python.

I would suggest looking at [this forum post](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?237761-Blender-2-6-Set-keyframes-using-Python-script) to learn how to set up the animation you want via python script.

Python can then be used to render a series of images (of the hand) like this:

```
for i in range(last_frame):
    bpy.ops.anim.change_frame(frame = i)
    bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = '/home/user/Pictures/frame%d.jpg'%i
    bpy.ops.render.render()
```